# Show AdMob interstitial ads multiple times on button click from a composable in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to show an interstitial ad by calling the bellow function each time a button is clicked from a composable. It works alright for the first click but doesn't get loaded for the next clicks. What am I missing here?

```
fun loadInterstitial(context: Context) {
    InterstitialAd.load(
        context,
        context.getString(R.string.ad_id_interstitial),
        AdRequest.Builder().build(),
        object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                mInterstitialAd = null
                Log.d("MainActivity", adError.message)
            }

            override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
                mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Ad was loaded.")
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Here is the [rest of the interstitial code](https://github.com/rawhasan/compose-exercise-ad-network/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/adnetwork/AdMob.kt) if necessary.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 'onAdDismissedFullScreenContent' load interstitial ads again

Comment: @TusharLathiya I'm calling this function from there too. But no result.

Comment: A.) Are you sing test IDs? B.) Which log event do you receive? Ad loaded or failed to load?

Comment: "Ad loaded" for the first time, nothing afterward. Didn't get your first question.

Comment: Are you using test IDs? *

Comment: If nothing is logged afterwards, it implies the code is not  being re-executed which would have something to do with your implementation

Comment: I don't need the interstitial code. I need the calling block. Not just the block, pass the Composable as well.

Comment: Must be a problem with recomposition

Comment: @MARSK [Here is the code](https://github.com/rawhasan/compose-exercise-ad-network/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/adnetwork/MainActivity.kt)

Comment: Where is the `showInterstitial` method?

Comment: @MARSK [Here](https://github.com/rawhasan/compose-exercise-ad-network/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/adnetwork/AdMob.kt)

Comment: Ok done! Check the asnwer

Comment: Oh you can remove the link now. It's not required

Comment: Or maybe keep it for other readers for future reference. As you like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok from the link pasted in the comment, I got this code:-

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            AdNetworkTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    AdNetworkApp()
                }
            }
        }

        // initialize the Mobile Ads SDK
        MobileAds.initialize(this) { }

        // load the interstitial ad
        loadInterstitial(this)

        // add the interstitial ad callbacks
        addInterstitialCallbacks(this)
    }
}
```

Clearly, the method being called in the `setContent` block is the problem.

The `setContent` block is executed only once until some factor like screen rotation or something to that effect triggers a hundred point recomposition. Now, you are calling the loading method in the `setContent`. Hence, the ad is loaded for the first time (so you see the logs for the first time). Afterwards, you do not call it anywhere at all. No ads loaded - nothing to show.

You can check this by rotating your screen. The ad will be loaded once more then.

Ok, solution could be to just go ahead and place the loading call in the `onClick` of the Button itself. I don't think anything else would be necessary.

Comment: Can you also please suggest, what will be the best way to display the interstitial once before showing the activity? If I call the show method after loading the ad in `onCreate`, it shows the `The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet` log.

Comment: Could you ask another question for this? There is not enough space in the comment to answer it. Moreover, it might just help the community if it is a question, independently